# Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I got a problem with including AngularJS/javascript into my html document. Every time i load my index.html i got this error:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8888/assets/angular/1.2.9/angular-route.js". index.html:17
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8888/assets/angular/1.2.9/angular.js".
```

This are my script tags:

```
<script src="./assets/angular/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./assets/angular/1.2.9/angular-route.js"></script>
```

What i have tried so far:

Include `<?php Header("Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=UTF-8"); ?>`,
Defining that the script tag text/javascript is or application/javascript

I hope that you guys can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting `type="text/javascript"` in your script tags

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is checking that the script files actually contain the intended javascript and not other content. Try it against the Angualr cdn to rule out issues with the local files.